# Google Play in-app billing v3, signature blank

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing, signature

My app using in-app billing v3 (UNMANAGED PRODUCT) and fully test with a signed apk, it works perfect on my android phone. After i release to production, got one purchase today, its my first purchase, but no signature received! i use my test account purchase again, got signature, but how come this buyer device submit blank signature to me?! Weird!

i check my Google Wallet records, its Green color icon, mean "The customer's credit card was successfully charged"! Im following the implementation below:

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
   if (requestCode == 1001) {           
      int responseCode = data.getIntExtra("RESPONSE_CODE", 0);
      String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");
      String dataSignature = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");

      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         try {
            //JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
            //String sku = jo.getString("productId");
            //alert("You have bought the " + sku + ". Excellent choice, adventurer!");

            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // submit 'purchaseData' and 'dataSignature' to my server 
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


          }
          catch (JSONException e) {
             //alert("Failed to parse purchase data.");
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
   }
}
```

my server only receive purchaseData but dataSignature is blank. anyone can help ? in what case will cause this issue?

Comment: Are you sure it's blank, or maybe the coding submitting it failed?

Comment: i got log all the request url, its like xxxxx.php?purchaseData={xxxxxxxxx}&dataSignature=&uid=xxxxx
im sure my iab implementation is correct , coz i try purchase with my test account, and my server have receive signature.

Comment: I would wait for another purchase. If it fails with same reason, I would contact Google Play support. I use IABv3 too and everything works just fine.

Comment: make sure you are using real product instead of test products(android.test.purchased,etc.) or you forget to replace real products instead of test products while exporting signed apk. Google gives response as a blank signature when you are trying to purchase test products. You'll receive signatures with real purchases.

Comment: i never use android.test.purchased, i use my own products.

Comment: 2nd purchase come in today, successfully charged and updated in my server with valid Signature code. still no idea why the first purchase no signature code.... possible he/she not download from Google play ?

Answer (score 0):

make sure if you haven't change in the RC_REQUEST constants then it should be 10001 instead of 1001, and if you have manually changed it then you have to change the constants for these three code.

**Constants:**

```
// (arbitrary) request code for the purchase flow   
static final int RC_REQUEST = 10001;
```

**Purchase Request:**

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_GAS, RC_REQUEST,
                    mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload_consumeItem);
```

**onActivityResult:**

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult(" + requestCode + "," + resultCode + ","
                + data);

        if (mHelper == null)
            return;

        if (requestCode == 10001) {

            int responseCode = data.getIntExtra("RESPONSE_CODE", 0);
            String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");
            Log.d("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA", ">>>" + purchaseData);
            String dataSignature = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");
            Log.d("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE", ">>>" + dataSignature);
            String continuationToken = data
                    .getStringExtra("INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN");
            Log.d("INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN", ">>>" + continuationToken);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    Log.d("purchaseData", ">>>" + purchaseData);
                    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                    String sku = jo.getString("productId");
                    alert("You have bought the " + sku
                            + ". Excellent choice, adventurer!");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    alert("Failed to parse purchase data.");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                // } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                Toast.makeText(AppMainTest.this,
                        "Sorry, you have canceled purchase Subscription.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if (resultCode == IabHelper.BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED) {
                Toast.makeText(AppMainTest.this, "Item already owned",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

    }
```

Let me know it will solve your problem or not.

Hope it will solve your problem.